# Assigning a clustered index on a two column table with two foreign key conditions

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design, indexing

I have a table which has two columns, both of which are of the int datatype and not null.

Column A is the primary key and is referenced as a many to one relationship as a foreign key from another table.

Column B is a foreign key that references one other table with a many to one relationship.

The user will never directly query against column A, it will only be used as a join. Queries will often use column B, particularly in the where clause.

What is the best option for a clustered index? In a larger table I would probably make the primary key non-clustered and put a clustered index on column B, would this be different with less columns?

The table will be updated monthly with a relatively small dataset.

Comment: But if Column B is foreign key with repeating values it cannot be a clustered index

Comment: Actually, you can have a clustered index on columns with repeating values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since column A is a primary key which is referenced by other tables, I am assuming that it will not be changed too often (probably it won't be changed at all). Also considering that it's an int column, it's probably a good choice for the clustered index. See http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/

I would also create a non-clustered index on column B, especially if it has a high cardinality. But even if the cardinality is medium, an index would still be useful on column B, for faster checks of the FK in case someone tries to delete something from the referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

You did not tell us enough about the columns to really decide which one to use. The best choice for clustered index column(s) are ones that take up the least amount of room, are unique as possible (SQL Server will make them unique if necessary) and very important, to avoid page splits, are increasing.

Comment: What other information would be helpful @benjamin moskovits?

Comment: Thats it pretty much. There is a lot to consider when it comes to index creation and mainteance and a great series to read through is: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/ You have to remember that all other indexes (on a table) will use the clustered index (unless its an included index or the data requested is part of the index) to get to the data. So you want as few pages to be stand between the program and the actual data. Narrow clustered index = lots of indexes keys per page so fewer pages are read.